# Dynamic Programming : Concept

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

True or False:

> Any problem that can be solved using dynamic programming has a polynomial time worst case time complexity with respect to its input size.

Are there any DP solutions which are not polynomial?

Thank you.

Comment: Many NP-complete problems can be solved using DP, for example Traveling Salesman and Longest Path.  Obviously these DP solutions are not polynomial-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dynamic programming algorithm for the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Dynamic_programming_in_advance_algorithm) for which the worst-case complexity is `O(Wn)` where `W` is the capacity of the knapsack and `n` is the number of items. Such a runtime bound is termed as *pseudo polynomial* (as a value which is encoded in the instance occurs) and cannot be considered as polynomial in the input size. So, short answer: false.

Furthermore, the original question is formulated a bit misleading; the runtime complexity refers to a specific algorithm, not the problem itself.

Answer (score 0):

There are many. The above example is one. Another popular example is dynamic programming solution of Traveling Salesman problem which runs in O(n2^n) time. Note that a brute force solution of Traveling Salesman takes O(n!) time, compared to that a dynamic programming solution is better.